Horror movie (following ghost to find head in the refrigerator)
I've been searching for a horror movie for many years. I remember I watched this when I was about 10-12 (1980-1982).
A young woman spends the night in an old house (probably a hotel). 
In the house, lived an old woman with two sons (they were already adults). At night, the young woman wakes up because she heard a weird noise. Then she sees a ghost. This ghost takes her to the kitchen, she opens the refrigerator and finds mutilated bodies! 
The old woman and the sons realise someone has found out their secret and start to chase her (one of the guys with a shotgun, and the other with a chainsaw or an axe (don't remember this very well). The heroine runs out of the house, gets in her car and runs over one of the guys, and shoots the other one. 
She then goes to the nearest police station, where she tells the whole story in panic. The sheriff thinks she's crazy and puts her into prison. She spends there the rest of the night. There was a curse saying she could die before 6 AM.
Suddenly, the prisoner has a visitor (near 6 AM). It was the old woman in the hotel! She stabs her to death just before 6 AM. 

Could this be Ghostkeeper (1981)?

Three friends on a New Year's Eve snowmobiling excursion find
themselves stranded at an abandoned lodge where the elderly female
innkeeper is concealing a sinister secret.

There's a scene where a mysterious presence guides one of the house guests into an ice cellar where they discover a pile of bodies. The elderly housekeeper's sons are protecting her secret, that the basement is home to a literal monster!



